# Detect and Initiate celery worker in Python Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

Normally I run the following in terminal to start the worker process

```
celery -A myapp worker --loglevel=info
```

What I want to achieve now is that with python code

1. I will check whether they are worker process being initiated,
2. if not only I run this command (with python code)

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for that as Celery gives you standard way to do it...

> --pidfile PIDFILE     Optional file used to store the process pid. The
> program won't start if this file already exists and
> the pid is still alive.

So simply change how you start your worker to something like `celery -A myapp worker --loglevel=info --pidfile celery1.pid`

If you open another terminal and run the command I wrote above, it will not run as the PID file is already created.